# How to retrieve a list of categories/ tag in Wordpress REST API

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know how to get a list of categories in Wordpress JSON Rest API?
It seems the current API does not support retrieve list of categories (While XML-RPC does).

http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

Answer (score 7):

Per [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/) page you could hit http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories. This may be an addition to v2 of the Rest API, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I just tried this out, It retrieves the categories, but not all of them. Must be a bug.

Comment: My answer is 4 years old so I'd recommend revisiting the official WordPress docs.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: As of August 2019, the JSON API plugin is not available due to security concerns.**

Im was trying to make andriod app out of my wordpress site. Thanks to JSON API that was possible but got real headace. There was no any documentation for request syntax.

After 2 hrs of research, I finally dug something out. First thing to know, there are 3 types of request mode:

**1. Implicit mode**

JSON query use non empty value i.e "json=1".Examples:

- http://www.example.com/?json=1
- http://www.example.com/?p=47&json=1
- http://www.example.com/tag/banana/?json=1

**2. Explicit mode**

JSON query use known string value i.e "json=get_recent_post".Examples:

- http://www.example.org/?json=get_recent_posts
- http://www.example.org/?json=get_post&post_id=47
- http://www.example.org/?json=get_tag_posts&tag_slug=banana

**3. Permalink mode**

No JSON query but user friendly permalinks are used for request i.e "/api/get_recent_post".Examples:

- http://www.example.org/api/get_recent_posts/
- http://www.example.org/api/get_post/?post_id=47
- http://www.example.org/api/get_tag_posts/?tag_slug=banana

Also, syntax for listing category is:

**http://blog.example.com/?json=get_category_index**

Also other important basic request are:

1. **http://blog.example.com/?json=get_tag_index**(To get list of Tag)
2. **http://blog.example.com/?json=get_author_index**(To get list of Author)
3. **http://blog.example.com/?json=get_page_index**(To get list of Page)
4. **http://blog.example.com/?json=get_date_index**(To get list of Date)

More details can be found in this [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/). Hope this will save someone's time who is not from wordpress background like me.

Answer (score 2):

With current versions of Wordpress 4.9.8 usually categories can be fetched with the builtin-API this way:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories
```

However, there seems to be a bug that will not fetch all categories, at least if you were using parent- and child-categories.

I added a small PHP-script to our wordpress-installation to retrieve ALL categories properly:

```
<?php

/** Make sure that the WordPress bootstrap has run before continuing. */
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

// Redirect to https login if forced to use SSL
if ( force_ssl_admin() && ! is_ssl() ) {
    if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
        exit();
    } else {
        wp_safe_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        exit();
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(get_categories());
```

Notice:

For testing purposes you should be aware that `get_categories`-function will return only those that are already associated with at least one (published?) article.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: As of August 2019, The JSON API plugin is closed due to security reasons. This answer is therefore deprecated.**

finally workable steps:

1. install wordpress plugin: `JSON API`
   [image: wordpress plugin JSON API]
2. use `get_category_index` api, format is: `http://www.example.com/api/get_category_index`

then can got response categories:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 332,
    "categories": [{
        "id": 4637,
        "slug": "soft_360",
        "title": "360",
        "description": "",
        "parent": 4618,
        "post_count": 2
    }, {
        "id": 4498,
        "slug": "amazon",
        "title": "Amazon",
        "description": "",
        "parent": 3390,
        "post_count": 29
    }, {
    ......
    }, {
        "id": 860,
        "slug": "default_classification",
        "title": "\u9ed8\u8ba4\u5206\u7c7b",
        "description": "",
        "parent": 17,
        "post_count": 3
    }]
}
```

more info can refer official document:
[JSON API — WordPress Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/)

Comment: This looks perfect but when I installed it I get Fatal error: Call to a member function run() on null in /home/*mydomain*/public_html/api/index.php on line 23. so perhaps this plugin is 2 years old and no longer compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the JSON API supplied by Jetpack, you may be out of luck. Looking at their API documentation (which they claim to be automatically updated), there is no reference to getting a list of categories. If it helps, though, you *can* get information about each individual category.

I just tried http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/$site/categories and it returned nothing. Sorry.

http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = [
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'parent' => 0
];

function _get_child_terms( $items ) {
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
      $item->children = get_terms( 'category', array( 'child_of' => $item->term_id, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
      if ( $item->children ) _get_child_terms( $item->children );
    }
    return $items;
}

$terms = _get_child_terms( get_terms( $args ) );
echo json_encode( $terms );
```

Answer (score -3):

try this `<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not inside wordpress and is looking for a way to access it through exposed wp API.

Comment: OP wants it via an API