# WP REST API not retrieving all categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am developing a project that is using the WP REST API. After some tests, I realized that it's not retrieving all the categories based on what I am trying to GET. In precise, there are supposed to be 21 results but only 10 come up. Is there some kind of restriction that I am not seeing? Any settings that I'll have to change.

Here is what I am trying:

`https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?parent=97`

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158417/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-categories-tag-in-wordpress-rest-api/31762279#31762279) post here, but some of the answers relied on using the WordPress JSON API, which is a plugin that is no longer available due to security concerns.

TIA

Comment: Would I be able to know why this question got a downvote? I want to make the appropriate changes so the community would benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

I had to look at [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#arguments) more closely. In terse, The default result shows a count of 10. Specifying the per page would change that. So:

`https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?parent=97&per_page=X`
(Change X to the respective number)