# WordPress REST API not retrieving all data

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am working with the REST API by Wordpress and I am trying to get the tags from the site and sort them in descending order by count. However, I am not getting all the respective tags nor are they being sorted.

I noticed some posts that talked [about a JSON API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158417/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-categories-tag-in-wordpress-rest-api/31762279#31762279), but the plugin doesn't exist anymore. Is there a way I can retrieve all data through the REST API?

For instance: `http://example.org/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?order=desc`

Thanks

Comment: @FluffyKitten I beg your pardon. But my question is much different. The linked post is experiencing problems with the amount of data. I am having issues with getting *the right* data in the respective order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your example there is you aren't giving the attribute it needs to sort. So while it does know that it needs to sort the tags in `desc` order, you'll have to specify the `orderby` attribute.

So something like:

`http://example.org/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?orderby=count&order=desc`

This would list out the tags in descending order by their count.